# Como apresentar o resultado de um formulário na mesma pagina?

Tags: php, formulário

Tenho um formulário que me dá o resultado em outra página, mas gostaria que o resultado aparecesse na mesma página.

```
 <form name="calc" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="resultado.php"> <input type="text" id="Peso" name="peso" required="">
        <input type="text" id="Altura" name="altura" required="">
        <input type="text" id="Peso" name="peso" required="">
        <input type="submit" class="button-green" value="CALCULAR">
</form>
```

**resultado.php**

```php
<div id="resultado">
        <?php 
$peso = $_GET['peso'];
$altura = $_GET['altura'];


$conta1 = $altura*$altura;
$conta2 = $peso/$conta1;


$resultado = number_format($conta2);


if(isset($resultado) && $resultado != '0'){; 
echo '<h1>Seu IMC é:</h1>';
echo '<h2>'.$resultado.'</h2>';
}else{
echo '<h1>Por favor, utilize apenas numeros!</h1>'; 
}
?>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 9):

Você precisa:

- Adicionar o código de resultado.php no mesmo arquivo do formulario.
- Deixar o `action` vazio ou colocar `#` no form.
- Verificar se existe algum valor em `$_GET`, use [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) para isso.

Um exemplo simples:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);

if(!empty($_GET) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){
    $nome = $_GET['nome'];
    echo 'valor recebido: '. $nome;
}   
?>

<form action="#">
    <input type="text" name="nome" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar o método `PHP_SELF`, mas é preciso alterar mais alguns detalhes no seu código:

1 - Utilizei o método `post`, (mas você pode usar o `GET`) e verifiquei com `isset` se a variável `$_POST` não estava vazia, pois, caso contrário, como disse o @rray, já na primeira vez que abrir a página vai aparecer o resultado considerando os campos com 0 e 0.

2 - Pelo que entendi, tem um campo a mais no seu HTML (duas vezes o campo peso).

3 - A formatação da saída com o `number format` requer 3 parâmetros, e você não estava passando nenhum.

Segue abaixo o código normalizado com o que acho que é o comportamento que você espera:

```
<form name="calc" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
    <label for="Peso"> Peso
    <input type="text" id="Peso" name="peso" required="">
    </label>
    <label for="Altura"> Altura
    <input type="text" id="Altura" name="altura" required="">
    </label>
    <input type="submit" class="button-green" value="CALCULAR">
</form>

<div id="resultado">
    <?php
    if (isset ($_POST)) {
        $peso = isset($_POST['peso']) ? $_POST['peso'] : false;
        $altura = isset($_POST['altura']) ? $_POST['altura'] : false;
        if (isset($peso) && $peso > 0 && isset($altura) && $altura > 0) {
            $conta1 = $altura * $altura;
            $conta2 = $peso / $conta1;
            $resultado = number_format($conta2, 2, ".", ",");

            var_dump($altura);
            var_dump($peso);

            if (isset($resultado) && $resultado != '0') {
                ;
                echo '<h1>Seu IMC é:</h1>';
                echo '<h2>' . $resultado . '</h2>';
            }
            if (isset($resultado) && $resultado < 17) {
                echo 'é menor que 17';
            } else {
                echo '<h1>Por favor, utilize apenas numeros!</h1>';
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Veja no Ideone [o IMC de um magricelo](https://ideone.com/hnnpiY). :)

Comment: :P olhe como está o `method` do seu form. Lembre de validar se vem algo na requisição, se não ao acessar a primeira vez é gera um warning de undefined index: x. De resto é isso ai :) +1

Comment: hehe Sim, eu tava vendo isso depois que li a sua resposta... vou editar aqui  valeu +1

Comment: obrigado amigo deu certo :)

Comment: tenho outra duvida para colocar if com botão radio podemos ir chat?

Comment: Então @kaiquemix, é melhor você criar outra pergunta. O SOpt funciona como um repositório de dúvidas sobre programação, e foi idealizado para ajudar outros usuários que tenham as mesmas dúvidas. Mas não se acanhe, pode fazer quantas perguntas quiser, desde que elas sejam objetivas, bem formatadas, etc... da forma como você fez esta. :)

Comment: eu estou tentando fazer algo assim:
    if (isset($resultado) < 17) {
        echo 'é menor que 17';
    }

porem não aparece nada..

Comment: É difícil responder em comentário, o melhor é você criar outra pergunta, mas tenta `if (isset($resultado) && $resultado < 17) { echo 'é menor que 17'; }`...

Comment: @gustavox como faço para o resultado tbm ser numero quebrado pois posso colocar 1.80 e 50.0 e o resultado só aparece inteiro

Comment: Então, isso é praticamente outra pergunta... De qualquer forma, eu falei sobre isso na resposta (dá uma olhada no código)... Você colocou os parâmetros do `number format`? A variável `$resultado` está assim: `$resultado = number_format($conta2, 2, ".", ",");` ? Detalhe importante: Na entrada (no campo `input`) tem que estar com `.` e não com `,`...

Comment: ta assim:  $resultado = number_format($conta2);

Comment: Então, mas tem que estar assim: `$resultado = number_format($conta2, 2, ".", ",");`.

Comment: coloquei obrigado :)

Answer (score 1):

Tente:

```
<?php

if ( count( $_GET ) && isset( $_GET['peso'] ) && isset( $_GET['peso'] ) ) { ?>
    // Digite o código do cálculo do resultado aqui
    Fazer novo cálculo
<?php } else { ?>
    // Digite o código do formulário aqui
}
```