# GET/POST para a mesma página?

Tags: php, html

Olá, sou iniciante em PHP e estou seguindo algumas vídeos-aulas, em uma passamos parâmetros via `GET` ou `POST` (tanto faz) para a mesma página do formulário, o objetivo é apenas trabalhar com `radiobox` e `checkbox`, porém estou com dois problemas, primeiramente vou colocar o código da página:

```
<?php
    $escolha = $_GET['cor'];
    $termos = $_GET['concorda'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Produtos</title>

<style> 
    #azul{color: blue;}
    #verde{color: green;}
    #vermelho{color: red;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form method="get" action="if_else.php">
        <table>  
        <tr>
             <td><h1>Escolha uma cor:</h1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p id="azul"><input type="radio" name="cor" value="0">Azul</p>
                <p id="verde"><input type="radio" name="cor" value="1">Verde</p>
                <p id="vermelho"><input type="radio" name="cor" value="2">Vermelho</p>
            </td>
            <?php 
            if($escolha == 0)
            {
                echo '<td bgcolor="blue"></td>';
            }
            else if($escolha == 1)
            {
                echo '<td bgcolor="green"></td>';
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<td bgcolor="red"></td>';
            }
            ?>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="concorda"/> Concordo com tudo.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php
                if($termos)
                {
                    echo "Concordor com os termos!";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "Não concordou.";
                }
                ?>
            </td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Pronto"/></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Desculpem a má formatação, etc, é apenas com intuito de praticar php.

**Problema 01:**

Na primeira vez que acesso a página não tenho valores para as variáveis `escolha` e `termos`, logo o `apache` aponta erro, como varia para resolver isso?

**Problema 02:**

Quando não marco o `checkbox` e aperto no `submit` a variável `termos` não recebe nada e o `apache` aponta erro novamente.

Onde estou errando? Agradeço desde já.

Comment: [Como apresentar o resultado de um formulário na mesma pagina?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102659/91)

Comment: Obrigado, olhando aí consegui fazer, vou postar como ficou.

Comment: No caso, para complementar, seria possível eu fazer isso em tempo real? Ou seja, quando o usuário apertar no radio ele mudar a cor sem ter que pressionar o botão?

Comment: Você pode usar javascript para fazer isso, caso precise de alguma informação do php use ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, com o link de @rray ficou assim:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['cor']))
       $escolha = $_GET['cor'];
    else
       $escolha = 0;
    if(isset($_GET['concorda']))
        $termos = $_GET['concorda'];
    else
       $termos = "off";

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Produtos</title>

<style> 
    #azul{color: blue;}
    #verde{color: green;}
    #vermelho{color: red;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form method="get" action="#">
        <table>  
        <tr>
             <td><h1>Escolha uma cor:</h1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p id="azul"><input type="radio" name="cor" value="0">Azul</p>
                <p id="verde"><input type="radio" name="cor" value="1">Verde</p>
                <p id="vermelho"><input type="radio" name="cor" value="2">Vermelho</p>
            </td>
            <?php 
            if($escolha == 0)
            {
                echo '<td bgcolor="blue"></td>';
            }
            else if($escolha == 1)
            {
                echo '<td bgcolor="green"></td>';
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<td bgcolor="red"></td>';
            }
            ?>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="concorda"/> Concordo com tudo.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php
                if($termos == 'on')
                {
                    echo "Concordo com os termos!";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "Não concordou.";
                }
                ?>
            </td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Pronto"/></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Como podem ver, alterei o recebimento das variáveis, para receber do `GET` ou `POST` somente quando tiver um valor passado, e se não tiver colocar `0` e `off` nas variáveis. Por fim, mudei também a condição do checkbox, agora verificando se ela é `on`, pois antes estava apenas verificando se ela existe.